# Applying wysiwyg editor after .load

Tags: jquery, wysiwyg

I am loading a form via jquery AJAX, and I am trying to implement a wysiwyg editor to a textarea.

The textarea itself is fine when loading the page, however when the div #customerForm is reloaded (it contains the textarea) like this:

```
$("#customerForm").html(loading).load(filename);
$('#noteArea').wysiwyg();
```

I cant get it to load.  The code above is in a seperate .JS file loaded in the main page, so I'm wondering if it is having trouble referencing the function on the fly.  The editor was taken from:

https://github.com/akzhan/jwysiwyg

If anyone has any better jquery editors to suggest I'd be open to them, however this one is small and nice and what I wanted.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you checked the console for any errors? Unless `loading' is a variable, you'll be getting an error immediately as it isn't a text string.

Comment: loading and filename are both variables set earlier in the JS, and it works fine, even with the .wysiwyg line in there, and the code after that.  I'll check for errors though!

Comment: No, there are no console errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`.load()`](http://jqapi.com/#p=load) function works asynchronously (see the [source of the function](http://james.padolsey.com/jquery/#v=1.7.2&fn=jQuery.fn.load), it uses `.ajax()` internally and the `async` property [defaults to `true`](http://jqapi.com/#p=jQuery.ajax)). This means the following line is executed before the content was loaded. Try initializing the editor in the callback:

```
$('#customerForm').load(filename, function() {
  $('#noteArea').wysiwyg();
});
```

Comment: Thank you! that sorted it out.  I'll remember that in the future.  Thank you.

Comment: You're welcome. `async` is a common root for errors with everything `.ajax()`-related.

Answer (score 0):

use [complete callback of load function](http://api.jquery.com/load/):

```
$("#customerForm").html(loading).load(filename, function(){
$('#noteArea').wysiwyg();
});
```